# How do Python functions work inside the memory?

Tags: python, function, stack

Let's take a simple code snippet:

```
def sum(a, b):
   return a + b

print(sum(3, 4))
```

• Do `Python` functions use stack?
  — the same way in `C`.

• Is it almost the same process as `C` programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. C does not require any stack to exist - but most *implementations* use one. No stack is required for a Python interpretor, and most implementation does not use any (at least directly).
2. From a programmer point of view, both C and Python are procedural languages: you can define and use functions in both, with reasonably close syntaxes. Main differences is that Python support classes and modules, while C allow low level access to the memory.

   From a usage point of view, C is a fully compiled language: translation unit are compiled then linked into executable programs. Python can be used in interactive interpreted mode: you can define a function, and immediately use it in an interactive way.

   From a system point of view, some Python interpretors are written in C (for example the standard CPython) or in other languages (Jython uses Java), while C compilers are normally written in C and assembly language - even if nothing prevents to write a C compiler in Python...

For those reasons, C is called a low level language (closer to the system and hardware), while Python is called a high level language or even script language because it can be used in interactive interpreted mode.

Comment: If it doesn't require stack, then how do functions in Python work in memory?

Comment: @NirajRaut: In Python a function is an object with parameters and a code block. When you call a function, you assign values to the parameters and execute the code block. The underlying language is likely to use a stack somewhere, but not at the Python language level. Object in Python aredynamically created in a heap way, and are garbage collected when no live variable refers them directly or indirectly. This is very different from the C memory management.

Comment: If they are objects, do they remain in memory until the entire program is executed?

Comment: @NirajRaut: a code block is a sequence of instructions. In many Python implementations, they are translated in an intermediary level language, more or less the same way that Java code in translated in a binary language to be later interpreted by a JVM. I am sorry but these are concepts  for which SO is not the best tool

Comment: As any other object function objects could be garbage collected if they were no longer reachable, but in common use case, this is very unlikely to happen.

Comment: If a function doesn't use a stack in Python, then how is recursion implemented in Python if function objects are allocated on heap?

Comment: AFAIK, for each new call new objects are allocated. There is of course a program stack.

Comment: What's the use of a program stack? Does it maintain stack frames that contain some information?